# How do I limit results to only those data frame rows and columns that contain 0s?

Tags: string, r, matching, approximate

I am doing approximate string matching in R. I am rather inexperienced with this technique, but because I want to find instances where my x strings match parts of my y strings exactly, I am only interested in Levenshtein scores of 0 (is this the correct approach?).

What's the most convenient way to subset the results? Because I have about 10k columns and 1k rows, I'm not sure there's any way to efficiently visualize the results either. I apologize for the lack of tact in this question. I just lack experience with this.

Comment: welcome to SO, it is hard to answer when we do not have a minimal dataset to see what your data looks like and some code, or what you want based on that dat. Please provide us some part of data, not all 1000*10000

Answer (score 1):

Using Mark's data, here's a way to build the indices with `apply`:

```
rows <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) any(!x))
cols <- apply(my.data, 2, function(x) any(!x))

my.data[rows, cols]
##   V2 V3 V4
## 1  0  2  1
## 3  1  1  0
## 5  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will retain all rows and columns that contain a zero.

```
set.seed(2234)

my.data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:2,20,replace=TRUE), nrow=5))
my.data

aa <- unique(which(my.data==0,arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])
bb <- unique(which(my.data==0,arr.ind=TRUE)[,2])

my.data2 <- my.data[sort(aa),sort(bb)]
my.data2

> my.data
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  2  0  2  1
2  2  2  1  2
3  2  1  1  0
4  2  2  2  1
5  1  0  0  0

> my.data2
  V2 V3 V4
1  0  2  1
3  1  1  0
5  0  0  0
```